# JsonWebTokenError: verify must be called asynchronous if secret or public key is provided as a callback

Tags: node.js, jwt, nestjs, jwks-rsa

I have got an observation from SonarQube - **Always sign JWTs and verify them using the `verify()` function before using the content of the token. Note that `verify()` returns decoded token value and there is no need to use the `decode()` function**. So i had to change my code to below version.

```
import { HttpException, HttpStatus, Injectable, NestMiddleware } from '@nestjs/common';
import { ConfigService } from '@nestjs/config';
import * as jwks from 'jwks-rsa';
import * as jwt from 'jsonwebtoken';

@Injectable()
export class TokenValidation implements NestMiddleware {

  constructor(private readonly configService: ConfigService) { }

  async use(req: any, _res: any, next: () => void) {

    const authHeader = req.headers.authorization;

    const token = this.extractBearerToken(authHeader);

    const client = jwks({
      jwksUri: this.configService.get('JWKS_URL'),
    });

    try {
      await new Promise<void>((resolve, reject) => {
        jwt.verify(token, async (header, callback) => {
          client.getSigningKey(header.kid, async (err, k) => {
            if (err) {
              reject(new HttpException('Token has expired', HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED));
            } else {
              const key = k.getPublicKey();
              callback(null, key);
              resolve();
            }
          });
        }, { algorithms: ['RS256'] });
      });
      next();
    } catch (error) {
      if (error instanceof jwt.JsonWebTokenError) {
        throw new HttpException('Token verification has failed', HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED);
      } else {
        throw new HttpException('Internal server error', HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

While sending a bearer token, I am getting `JsonWebTokenError: verify must be called asynchronous if secret or public key is provided as a callback`. Where am I going wrong? Requesting the community's help.